# Coudn"t find emulator.exe in eclipse after I updated my sdk..?

Tags: android, eclipse

After finishing updates with android api-22 and all other updates I am not able to open my sdk manager, it shows like "couldn't find emulator.exe (d:\eclipse\sdk\tools)"..
when I just open my tools folder I found only lib folder is available rest of the folders are deleted,I have no idea why it is happened...worried!!!

need help..thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would heavily recommend using android studio because eclipse is no longer supported by android developers.

Comment: Thanks...let me check that.

Answer (score 0):

Download SDK Tools 24.0.1 and Copy the platform-tools folder content to your sdk path > platform-tools folder

Once this error is removed then :

Open SDK Manager and update these things :

(1) Android SDK Tools

(2) Android Platform Tools

(3) Android Build Tools

Comment: yes...what I have done now is,I found one tools.zip folder in temp folder and I unzipped it and copied that folder and override it with tools folder...now its working...As you said I updated all tools in sdk manager.

Comment: what is my doubt is I don't have zipalign.jar inside tools...!!??so this will create a problem while signing in application to play store.

Comment: zipalign.jar should be present in tools.. try downloading latest sdk tools and build tools

Comment: download latest version sdk tools i think 24.1.1